# Converting between integer types

Tags: haskell, floating-point, int, typeclass

It's a pretty stupid question but I'm kinda lost. Here's the function

```
f :: (Bool,Int) -> Int
f (True,n) = round (2 ** n)
f (False,n) = 0
```

And here's an error I'm getting

```
No instance for (Floating Int)
  arising from a use of `**'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Floating Int)
In the first argument of `round', namely `(2 ** n)'
In the expression: round (2 ** n)
In an equation for `f': f (True, n) = round (2 ** n)
```

What should I add to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(**)` is floating-point exponentiation. You probably want to use `(^)` instead.

```
f :: (Bool,Int) -> Int
f (True,n)  = 2^n
f (False,n) = 0
```

It's helpful to look at the types:

```
Prelude> :t (**)
(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
Prelude> :t (^)
(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
```

The error message is telling you that `Int` is not an instance of the `Floating` typeclass, and therefore you can't use `(**)` on it directly. You could convert to some floating-point type and back, but here it is better to simply use the integral version directly. Also note that `(^)` only requires the *exponent* to be integral. The base can be of any numeric type.